# JavaScriptで作成したTableのボタンで、関数（function）を作動させたい。

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScriptで生成したTableにあるボタンに、関数（insertColumn）を実装したいです。
現在、プログラムでエラーが出ているので解決策を教えてください。
HTMLは`<input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(table)">`の部分、JSは`const insertColumn=(table)=>{ // Add a column to a Table let tbl = document.getElementById(this.closest(table)); let cell_1 = tbl.rows[0].insertCell(1);`
の部分でエラーが発生しています。
宜しくお願いします。

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>
        ProjectManagementSystem
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pms.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1>Manage Your Project</h1>
      <input type="button" class="AddPrj" value="Add a Project" onclick="addPrj('PMS')">
      <div id="PMS"></div>
    
      
      <input class="prjName" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
      <table id="tbl" class="PMStbl" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="button" class="AddCln" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(table)">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="date">
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>PIC</td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Task</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option value="dev">coding</option>
              <option value="rev">review</option>
              <option value="fix">fixed</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <script src=pms.js></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript

```
//1-Function to add a new column to a Table, which is already created by HTML
const insertColumn=(table)=>{
    // Add a column to a Table
    let tbl = document.getElementById(this.closest(table));
    let cell_1 = tbl.rows[0].insertCell(1);
    cell_1.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';
    let cell_2 = tbl.rows[1].insertCell(1);
    cell_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input your Name">';
    let cell_3 = tbl.rows[2].insertCell(1);
    cell_3.innerHTML = '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';
};




    //2-Function to Create a new Table
    const addPrj=(PMS)=>{
        //Get tag's IDs from the Table
        let $prjName = document.getElementsByClassName('prjName');
        let prjName =$prjName.length;
        let tableID = "tbl_"+String(prjName);
        let newPrjID = "prj_"+String(prjName);
        const newDiv = document.getElementById('PMS');
        //Create a new "Project Name" button
        let newPrj = document.createElement('input');
        newPrj.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newPrj.setAttribute("placeholder", "Project Name");
        newPrj.setAttribute("class", "prjName");
        newPrj.setAttribute("id",newPrjID);
    
   

    //Generate a new Table
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    table.setAttribute("id",tableID);
    let thead = document.createElement('thead');
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Insert a new button and a new table
    newDiv.insertBefore(table, newDiv.firstChild);
    newDiv.insertBefore(newPrj, newDiv.firstChild);

    // Creating and adding data to first row of the table
    let row_1 = document.createElement('tr');
    let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_1.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Add a Column" onclick="insertColumn(this.closest(table))">';
    let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
    heading_2.innerHTML = '<input type="date">';


    row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
    row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
    thead.appendChild(row_1);


    // Create 2nd row data
    let row_2 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_2_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_1.innerHTML = "PIC";
    let row_2_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_2_data_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Input Your Name">';

    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_1);
    row_2.appendChild(row_2_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_2);


    // Create 3rd row data
    let row_3 = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_3_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_1.innerHTML = "Task";
    let row_3_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    row_3_data_2.innerHTML = 
    '<select><option value="dev">coding</option><option value="rev">review</option><option value="fix">fixed</option></select>';

    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_1);
    row_3.appendChild(row_3_data_2);
    tbody.appendChild(row_3);

};
```

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。
Add a Columnボタン押下で発生します。

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick(index.html: 1:27)
Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick(index.html: 22:109)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

`insertColumn`が引数`table`を取るようにした意味が理解できないのですが、なんとなく推察するに、`insertColumn`は引数なし、つまりJavaScriptコードは`const insertColumn=()=>{`で、呼び出しは`insertColumn()`で良いのでは。